# SQL Server 2000 with JDK 1.6 Driver

Tags: jdbc, driver, sql-server-2000, java-6

I get the following error with the Combination of SQL Server 2000 and JDK version 1.6. Can anybody please guide me to the right driver to use for this combination?

"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: SQL Server version 8 is not supported by this driver"

Microsoft has stopped providing drivers for the older versions of SQL Server. At this point, I'm using the driver sqljdbc4.jar for JDK 1.6. I know for certain that this is not right as sqljdbc4 is for SQL server 2005 and above.

Please help me with this. I don't want to use jTDS driver jar for the purpose. Any other suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer!

The problem was with the Drvier version. Instead of using an sqljdbc4.jar(version 3), I was using sqljdbc4.jar(version 4).

The difference can be recognized by using the statement `connection.getMetaData().getDriverMajorVersion()` and `connection.getMetaData().getDriverMinorVersion()` on the connection object.

I hope this will help in a way to all those who are new to MS SQL Server.

Cheers!